# Track multiple search terms with twitter streaming

Tags: twitter

I would like to build a web application that tracks some user defined search terms in real-time and provides a real-time visualization.  http://www.monitter.com/ is an app I've found that is similar in its requirements. What is the appropriate API to use for it? Initially I thought the streaming API was the obvious choice, but the limitation of one concurrent connection means that I can only track one search term at a time(with one user account). I could get around this by making multiple user accounts, but that seems like the wrong approach.

I looked at user streams but the language for that API seems to be more geared towards desktop applications.

So, what is the most best API for my use case? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Investigating further using Firebug, I found that monitter.com simply polls the REST search api every second or so on the client side. This is what I ended up doing as well.

Answer (score 3):

Actually you can track up to 400 keywords/terms via one streaming API connection. 
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-api/methods#track

Depending on language you are using there are multiple interfaces you can use.
If you are using PHP, then I can suggest Phirehose as it works quite well and has multiple examples for different usages scenarios included.
http://code.google.com/p/phirehose/wiki/Introduction

Whats not there - when processing received tweets you will need to figure out how to match which tweet corresponds to which keyword/term because twitter streaming API gives all matching tweets in one stream.

Comment: Yeah I did investigate this. However, the tweets top out at ~3k per minute no matter how many search terms you put in, so they are down sampling it.

Comment: How can you scale the app when customers define more than 400 keywords?